# Two GOOGLEFINANCE formulae in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I am trying to incorporate a GOOGLEFINANCE formula in the GOOGLE SHEETS in one cell, say, F45, like the one in the following:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE(A45)-=GOOGLEFINANCE(A45, "CloseYest")
```

The Cell A45 has a string, such as `"GOOG"`. This gives Formula parse error. If I break them into 2 cells like:

`=GOOGLEFINANCE(A45)` in one cell and  `=GOOGLEFINANCE(A45, "CloseYest")` works perfectly.  No amount of `(((` or `)))` to separate the formula in the same cell works, and results in the same Formula parse error. For example, `=(=GOOGLEFINANCE(F45))-(=googlefinance(F45, "CloseYest"))` gives me parse error.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove extra `=` - it is necessary only in the beginning of the formula:

```cpp
=GOOGLEFINANCE(A45)-GOOGLEFINANCE(A45, "CloseYest")
```

Where `A45` is the cell with the name of a security.

Comment: Now, I have another error, which is : Error Function GOOGLEFINANCE parameter 1 value is invalid.

Comment: Have you changed `F45` in the suggested formula to the cell where the ticker ***GOOG*** is located in your sheet (maybe `A45`)?!

Comment: Yes!got it!! The cell reference is A45, not F45. After I changed it, I got the right answer. BTW, if the formula is complicated, it will still have only one = in the beginning, and rest of them, you don't need to have = in front of GOOGLEFINANCE() function?

Comment: @Balepur You need `=` only in the very beginning once.  After that you can just refer to the functions themselves, like `GOOGLEFINANCE` and others.

Comment: @Balepur I have updated the answer to use the same reference as in the question (`A45` instead of `F45`).  If this worked for you, could you mark the question answered, please.